# JDBC SQL Server Exception

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, classpath

I’m trying to connect a Java program with `MS SQL SERVER 2012` but Java throws the `exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I understand that the problem often is a result of that the `CLASSPATH` is not set up correctly for the driver. I have followed the directions from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) to add a `CLASSPATH`, but I still get the same exception.  When I type `“echo %CLASSPATH%"` in the command prompt I get a correct response. What have I missed?

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JDBCTest {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Can't find database driver: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the runtime environment for you application? are you sure that you add the correct jar file to your deployed application?

Comment: It seems your application is not loading the SQLServer Driver properly.

Comment: Can you also post the result of `echo CLASSPATH` in your console?

Comment: Use eclipse, it'll make your life much easier

Comment: sorry i could be wrong for a beginner the eclipse isnt the great tool to work ,, @ftom2

Comment: @ATR - there are so many tutorials to get you started....

Comment: try with command prompt , pass the connectivity jar as the option to ru your app ...exeute a class using  : `java -cp :/path/to/JARS/connector-java-bin.jar Classname ` this should resolve your issue

Comment: try to set the class path in the environment variables.. in the computer properties and check whether you are using the correct class with the valid packages..? i.e. of SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime environment for your application may not contain the appropriate jar file. 
The path that you have checked is only for your console environment. The application classpath is different from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public class connectURL {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Create a variable for the connection string.
String  Connectionurl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=YourDBName;user=UserName;Password=YourPassword"

            // Declare the JDBC objects.
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

                try {
                    // Establish the connection.
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);


                        String SQL = "";
                        stmt = con.createStatement();
                        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


                        while (rs.next()) {
                            ....
                        }
                }


            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                    if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                    if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

make sure that you download the driver jar file and put it at the right place

Answer (score 0):

If Class.forName fails it is a problem of classpath.

try this code to check your classpath:

```
    String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println("Working Directory:");
    System.out.println("\t"+userDir);
    System.out.println("Classpath:");
    String[] paths = classPath.split(";");
    for (String path : paths) {
        File pathFile = new File(path);
        String check = pathFile.exists()?"OK        ":"NOT-FOUND ";
        System.out.println("\t"+check+path);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all download `sqljdbc4.jar` from [`here`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)

Put this `.jar` in Your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. (Check if this file appears from your eclipse's lib if not then Refresh Your Project)[image]

And then run Your Project.